# Access Jenkins instance with shared-libraries for pipelines

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline

We were pretty hooked onto using some plugins which are not supported in pipelines anymore and would like to implement their usage in shared-libraries of our pipelines. One of the main items required for that would be to get hold of Jenkins Instance, can someone share a way to do that ?

1. Are there any restrictions or proper way to get hold of `Jenkins.getActiveInstance()` under "src" or "vars" folder ?

I have tried to get `Jenkins.getActiveInstance()` under src code as well vars code but it returns null, am I missing something here? any help will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try 'Hudson.instance'. This pipeline below works for me on Jenkins 2.32.x. You may have to do some script approvals or turn off the sandbox.

```
pipeline {

    agent none

    stages{

        stage('Instance Info') {

            steps {
                script {

                    def jenkinsInstance = Hudson.instance

                    for (slave in jenkinsInstance.slaves) {

                        echo "Slave: ${slave.computer.name}"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bill

Comment: Even with the sandbox turned off and this code running under a `@NonCPS` method, I still get `java.io.NotSerializableException: hudson.model.Hudson`.

Comment: Turns out I needed a `def` declaration on the variable I was assigning to `Hudson.instance`.  i.e., `def foo = Hudson.instance` works; `foo = Hudson.instance` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

This ticket can be closed, there were few issues :
1. Fix the access via (Manage Jenkins -> In script approval)
2. some scripts contain Non-cps code

Comment: this is not a ticket system - this is a Q&A platform.